# What is the name of this book about Earth becoming a second class planet to Starhome?

Tags: story-identification, books

The main character of this book was employed by the governments 'alien management' department and the plot of the book centered around terrorist threats to the place where aliens with enviromental needs were housed, and the fact that the only other human planet, based on the concept of efficiency and logic called Starhome was about to outclass Earth. There were blue aliens who legs bent backwards called 'Relgans'(or similar) and anti-hol was a thing (to sober up).

The book cover I remember had a rocketpad with a rocket on the front, either about to take off or in the process of, but I can't for the life of me remember the book's name. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [The Long Result](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2881664-the-long-result) by John Brunner. There are a [number of elements](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZFKRaKfwg4wC&pg=PT141&lpg=PT141&dq=Long%20Result%20By%20John%20Brunner%20%22blue%22&source=bl&ots=OTfbjt4oWI&sig=VWWdZEvcKSM5cB5Kgf6RaYEw_qE&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Long%20Result%20By%20John%20Brunner%20%22blue%22&f=false) that match your description;

- Planet called Starhome - **Check.**
- Aliens called *'Relgans*(?)' - **Check** (Re**gul**ans, actually)
- Book cover with rocket - **Check**
- Blue aliens - **Check**
- Legs that bend the wrong way - **Check** (described as "back-bent")
- Anti-hol - **Check** (described as "Anti-Alcohol")

[image]

Comment: That is exactly the book I was looking for. Thank you. Read it a long time ago and wanted to get an audio version if one existed.
This was the one I had, as you can see the spaceship made an impression :-)
http://www.sfreviews.com/graphics/John%20Brunner_1965_The%20Long%20Result.gif